# Editable NSTextField in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, swift

I have a view based NSTableView with some labels in my customized and subclassed view. One of the label should be editable, so therefore I set this NSTextField to editable.

But now I have two problems, I can't solve:

1) If I move the mouse over the editable NSTextField, the cursor don't change to the `IBeamCursor` (the edit cursor).

2) I need to double click at the label, to be able to edit. I want to have a single click. I found some solutions for this problem here at stackoverflow, the best one is to override the `acceptsFirstResponder` to return always true, but then, clicking at the NSTextField selects the whole text instead of placing the cursor at the clicked position.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry... this is a duplicate. I found this:

[NSTableView - select row and respond to mouse events immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572547/nstableview-select-row-and-respond-to-mouse-events-immediately/13579469#13579469)

You have to subclass `NSTableView`. My swift code:

```
class TableViewEditing: NSTableView {

    ...

    override func validateProposedFirstResponder(responder: NSResponder, forEvent event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Just one disadvantage: Sometimes entering the edit mode, it seems that the text is just shortly selected and deselected. But you can see, that this is a cocoa problem, it's the same for example in Apple reminders app.